# Possible Delay When Using NOW() in MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL and PHP through a book at the library. I was improving the security of the password encrypting system by changing the password storage from

```
password=SHA('password')
```

to

```
password=SHA(CONCAT('password', '--', registration_date))
```

where `registration_date` is the timestamp when the user registered.

The current code for registering users is:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, registration_date) 
VALUES ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', SHA(CONCAT('password', '--', NOW())), NOW());
```

Will I need to worry about the two different NOW() functions in there? Is there a possibility of them having slightly different times? I tried it with a couple of queries and it seemed to work ok.

If there is a problem, how would I fix it?

Comment: You better be very, very, very, very, very, very sure that the registration_date field can never, ever, ever, ever, ever get updated.  Otherwise you will find yourself with a sudden shortage of users.

Comment: @Larry - that would apply to the password field as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.)

As the manual shows by example, every evaluation of `NOW()` within a statement returns the same value, regardless of how much time has passed between the evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

On one server, you don't have to worry. From the documentation:

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute.

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) So the value will not change in one query.

You should watch out for statement based replication though. If there's a chance your database is replicated this way (for example for backups, or HA), then the slave may have a different `NOW()` than the master.

Comment: Good point about SBR. Master and slave may indeed have different `NOW()` values. But the values of `NOW()` in a row of the slave will be the same _in that row_. (I think this is what OP was concerned might fail.) If differences between master and slave `NOW()` values are a problem, then row based replication fixes that. Alternatively, one could perhaps play games with `SET TIMESTAMP` (which affects the value of `NOW()`) to work around the problem.